# unable to extract the table using bs4

Tags: html, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Hi I am trying to extract the table from this site:

[Target Site for Scrape](https://api.ofx.com/PublicSite.ApiService/SpotRateHistory/allTime/USD/ARS?DecimalPlaces=8&ReportingInterval=yearly)

I tried using bs4 as well as pd.read_html. Despite seeing the table tags in the "soup" I've not been able to make it find them. My guess is the data is loading in after. I would ideally like to do this without using selenium. Ive noticed it also has a dict like object called "var model" is there a way to access this through requests? Ive copied it from the source code and posted below.

Cheers

```
var model = {"CurrentInterbankRate":74.72140399,"CurrentInverseInterbankRate":0.01338305,"Average":15.14101240,"HistoricalPoints":[{"PointInTime":978307199999,"InterbankRate":0.99973015,"InverseInterbankRate":1.00027002},{"PointInTime":1009843199999,"InterbankRate":1.00000857,"InverseInterbankRate":0.99999155},{"PointInTime":1041379199999,"InterbankRate":2.63289734,"InverseInterbankRate":0.43403613},{"PointInTime":1072915199999,"InterbankRate":2.94796721,"InverseInterbankRate":0.34009351},{"PointInTime":1104537599999,"InterbankRate":2.94124008,"InverseInterbankRate":0.34012553},{"PointInTime":1136073599999,"InterbankRate":2.91477610,"InverseInterbankRate":0.54410527},{"PointInTime":1167609599999,"InterbankRate":3.07339545,"InverseInterbankRate":0.32538532},{"PointInTime":1199145599999,"InterbankRate":3.11525349,"InverseInterbankRate":0.32103202},{"PointInTime":1230767999999,"InterbankRate":3.16700443,"InverseInterbankRate":0.31621115},{"PointInTime":1262303999999,"InterbankRate":3.72898339,"InverseInterbankRate":0.26848343},{"PointInTime":1293839999999,"InterbankRate":3.91137986,"InverseInterbankRate":0.25571003},{"PointInTime":1325375999999,"InterbankRate":4.12870331,"InverseInterbankRate":0.24233673},{"PointInTime":1356998399999,"InterbankRate":4.54916212,"InverseInterbankRate":0.22016157},{"PointInTime":1388534399999,"InterbankRate":5.47453082,"InverseInterbankRate":0.18368720},{"PointInTime":1420070399999,"InterbankRate":8.11288453,"InverseInterbankRate":0.12367665},{"PointInTime":1451606399999,"InterbankRate":9.24612693,"InverseInterbankRate":0.10878823},{"PointInTime":1483228799999,"InterbankRate":14.75736653,"InverseInterbankRate":0.06790187},{"PointInTime":1514764799999,"InterbankRate":16.55924652,"InverseInterbankRate":0.06057628},{"PointInTime":1546300799999,"InterbankRate":28.14054973,"InverseInterbankRate":0.03813937},{"PointInTime":1577836799999,"InterbankRate":48.19220455,"InverseInterbankRate":0.02137447},{"PointInTime":1609459199999,"InterbankRate":70.63534275,"InverseInterbankRate":0.01430140},{"PointInTime":1631282400000,"InterbankRate":92.87351896,"InverseInterbankRate":0.01078530}]},
    txt = $$('TEXTAREA')[0],
    humanize = true && location.hash.indexOf('dehumanize') == -1,
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to scrape the table, because the data is already available in JSON format (among others). Simply append `&format=json` to the end of the URL like so:

https://api.ofx.com/PublicSite.ApiService/SpotRateHistory/allTime/USD/ARS?DecimalPlaces=8&ReportingInterval=yearly&format=json

and you get the following result:

```json
{
    "CurrentInterbankRate": 74.72140399,
    "CurrentInverseInterbankRate": 0.01338305,
    "Average": 15.14101240,
    "HistoricalPoints": [{
        "PointInTime": 978307199999,
        "InterbankRate": 0.99973015,
        "InverseInterbankRate": 1.00027002
    }, {
        "PointInTime": 1009843199999,
        "InterbankRate": 1.00000857,
        "InverseInterbankRate": 0.99999155
    }, {
        "PointInTime": 1041379199999,
        "InterbankRate": 2.63289734,
        "InverseInterbankRate": 0.43403613
    }, {
        "PointInTime": 1072915199999,
        "InterbankRate": 2.94796721,
        "InverseInterbankRate": 0.34009351
    }, {
        "PointInTime": 1104537599999,
        "InterbankRate": 2.94124008,
        "InverseInterbankRate": 0.34012553
    }, {
        "PointInTime": 1136073599999,
        "InterbankRate": 2.91477610,
        "InverseInterbankRate": 0.54410527
    }, {
        "PointInTime": 1167609599999,
        "InterbankRate": 3.07339545,
        "InverseInterbankRate": 0.32538532
    }, {
        "PointInTime": 1199145599999,
        "InterbankRate": 3.11525349,
        "InverseInterbankRate": 0.32103202
    }, {
        "PointInTime": 1230767999999,
        "InterbankRate": 3.16700443,
        "InverseInterbankRate": 0.31621115
    }, {
        "PointInTime": 1262303999999,
        "InterbankRate": 3.72898339,
        "InverseInterbankRate": 0.26848343
    }, {
        "PointInTime": 1293839999999,
        "InterbankRate": 3.91137986,
        "InverseInterbankRate": 0.25571003
    }, {
        "PointInTime": 1325375999999,
        "InterbankRate": 4.12870331,
        "InverseInterbankRate": 0.24233673
    }, {
        "PointInTime": 1356998399999,
        "InterbankRate": 4.54916212,
        "InverseInterbankRate": 0.22016157
    }, {
        "PointInTime": 1388534399999,
        "InterbankRate": 5.47453082,
        "InverseInterbankRate": 0.18368720
    }, {
        "PointInTime": 1420070399999,
        "InterbankRate": 8.11288453,
        "InverseInterbankRate": 0.12367665
    }, {
        "PointInTime": 1451606399999,
        "InterbankRate": 9.24612693,
        "InverseInterbankRate": 0.10878823
    }, {
        "PointInTime": 1483228799999,
        "InterbankRate": 14.75736653,
        "InverseInterbankRate": 0.06790187
    }, {
        "PointInTime": 1514764799999,
        "InterbankRate": 16.55924652,
        "InverseInterbankRate": 0.06057628
    }, {
        "PointInTime": 1546300799999,
        "InterbankRate": 28.14054973,
        "InverseInterbankRate": 0.03813937
    }, {
        "PointInTime": 1577836799999,
        "InterbankRate": 48.19220455,
        "InverseInterbankRate": 0.02137447
    }, {
        "PointInTime": 1609459199999,
        "InterbankRate": 70.63534275,
        "InverseInterbankRate": 0.01430140
    }, {
        "PointInTime": 1631282400000,
        "InterbankRate": 92.87351896,
        "InverseInterbankRate": 0.01078530
    }]
}
```

(with a little bit formatting).

Comment: Cheers mate what was the main clue to do that so I know what to look for in the future? I didn't realise you can just do that!

Comment: @JPWilson frequently APIs return data in your choice of formats, not just rendered HTML and JavaScript. There are links to JSON, XML, CSV, and JSV on the upper right of the page, but they were broken. I looked at their URLs and saw they had a `&format=XXX` parameter, so I just tried that on the URL you gave and it worked. It always pays to look under the hood a little, and as you gain experience you start to figure out common ways of doing things. Good luck!